# What is the IntelliJ equivalent from Eclipse, show file in the package explorer view

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I am more familiar in Eclipse and need the IntelliJ equivalent.  In Eclipse, I could open a java class, right click, show file in package explorer and it would highlight the file on the left.  What is the IntelliJ equivalent.

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for, but does ALT-F1 (or Navigate/Select In... in case it's not the same as on the Mac) do what you need?

Comment: No, that opens different views.  Let's say I have a file open, I need to highlight/select that file on the 'left' view.  E.g. I have expanded/exploded view on the left but can't find the file that I have open in the explorer.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can highlight a file you have open in the editor in a number of views using the `Select In...`menu that can be opened using `ALT-F1` when the editor window has the cursor.

The most usual ones (Project/Packages) are found under the menu opened by `ALT-F1` and then `right arrow`.

Comment: If using a Mac keyboard, you might have to use alt/option + fn + f1.

Answer (score 32):

You can also double click the circle/cross button ontop of the Project view

it will show you the current active file in the project structure

[image]

Comment: this is the best way!

Comment: You can also click the cog icon and select "Always Selected Opened Files" if you prefer it this way.

Answer (score 26):

You can turn on *Autoscroll from source* in [Project Tool Window](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/project-tool-window.html) so that the file/class to the left is scrolled to as soon as you open a file for edit.

> If this option is on, IntelliJ IDEA automatically navigates from a file in the editor to the corresponding node (file, class, field, method, etc.) in the Project tool window.
>   Note that selecting this option makes the Scroll to Source button   unavailable.

Comment: although the other answer is correct given the question, this is what actually everyone is looking for. +1

Comment: This should be the actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is called "select in project view".

You'd better edit your keymap ! (alt+F1 right arrow is not very efficient...)

> file > settings > keymap > select in project view : alt+E for example

Answer (score 0):

You can press Alt-Home, it goes to the navigation bar.

Go to or select the package by pressing left arrow.

Press F4 now to see it in the project view.